# RESTful API authentication/security

Tags: api, google-app-engine, authentication, python-2.7, api-key

I'm developing a RESTful API for my app on GAE python and right now I'm trying to figure out the best way to secure this API.
I have my own member/authentication mechanism on this app.

what is the best way to do this?

- having public/private key pairs
- becoming an OAuth provider
- HTTP authentication (seems very weak to me)
- other??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, discard HTTP Auth. It is not recommended in a true REST API since it resides on cookies.

I would go with OAuth. There's a library called [appengine_oauth_provider](https://github.com/mohangk/appengine_oauth_provider), which could helps you to start implementing your own provider.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the library is very old, do we have alternative ones?

Comment: Just curious: do you have a reference for REST API and cookies being irreconcilable?

Comment: @Drux, REST should be stateless, that's means a request should not depend on a previous one (i.e. an authentication request).

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez Fair enough in a "pure" sense (although one could perhaps argue that OAuth2 authentication tokens also carry a bit of state).

Comment: "HTTP Auth" usually refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication - which is stateless, because you add the header to every request. So it does not depend on a previous one. As long as it's protected by https, it's secure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Service Account for User Authentication. However, people still can register an account and use your API and surely your app engine bill will go up. They've just introduce Google Cloud Endpoints at Google I/O 2012. You will have a Client ID which will only use on your client application(Android,iOS).

[Google I/O 2012 - Building Android Applications that Use Web APIs with Yaniv Inbar and Sriram Saroop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dylFNrvZ_3U)

[Google I/O 2012 - Building Mobile App Engine Backends for Android, iOS and the Web](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4)

If you are interested in, you should try to sign up for trusted tester at

http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: as mentioned above i have my own authentication/member mechanism and i don't use google accounts to authenticate. will check the I/O videos. can't really find any examples of how the endpoints would look in python.

Comment: Unfortunately, we didn't have any Python examples ready at I/O, but we've recently shared some sample Python code with trusted testers. I'd definitely encourage you to sign up.